# associative array overwriting entries php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to build an associative array to save the following information. A url, a word, and a frequency (# of occurrences of that word on that webpage).

I want to be able to access the information where I enter a string for the url and word and receive the frequency, like this:

```
$test["somewhere.com"]["biology"] => 5
$test["somewhere.com"]["auto"] => 10
$test["elsewhere.com"]["biology"] => 7
```

Right now I am pulling the information out of a db one row at a time and am trying the following:

```
$test["$url"] =  array("$word" => "$freq");
```

After every iteration it gets over written. How do I change the syntax to avoid this situation? Is it possible to build the structure I want?

Thanks.

EDIT: 
I was assigning values to array in a while loop. I made the mistake of initializing the array within the loop. I wasn't overwriting entries, I was 
re-initializing the array unintentionally. That was my problem.

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: @AbraCadaver see edit. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You are reassigning `$test["$url"]` as a new array each time.  Use the full path:

```
$test[$url][$word] = $freq;
```

Also, no need for the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overwriting the first level contents, declare a new property for it. (without knowing how are you getting your urls, words and frequencies, the following is just an example)

```
$test = []
foreach($urls as $url => $words) {
   $test[$url]=[];
   foreach( $words as $word => $freq) {
      $test[$url][$word] = $freq;
   }
}
```

However, this looks awfully like trying to build an associative array that's already built.